# Log out after some time in Angular

Tags: angular

I have web sphere portlet app, my Angular application was loaded in portlet using iframe.

Portlet has a timeout. My Angular app calling its own Spring Boot API which doesn't care user session. If user is idle for some time, if portlet is timeout due to session time out, my Angular app is not timing out. Is there any way I can write timeout in Angular?

Idle timeout.

Comment: Here is an example of how implement an idle timeout in Angular: https://blog.bitsrc.io/how-to-implement-idle-timeout-in-angular-af61eefdb13b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-user-idle

I hope this can help.. This works angular 6 and above. try it.

Comment: This answer would be improved if there was a minmum example of usage